# Custom attribute constraints

Tags: delphi, attributes, rtti

How make custom attribute which can be used only with specific keyword? For example  attribute which can be places only above fields or only above public Boolean fields?

The point is to make something similat to Java @Target annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How make custom attribute which can be used only with specific keyword?

This is not possible in Delphi.